# Bash: find duplicates within a column, remove rows based on comparison of another column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a comma separated text file (no commas in example below for readability) containing several columns.

```
id               date
xyz_1567.n28     2017-08-09T18:36:38.000000Z
abc_2791.b87     2015-04-07T12:04:06.000000Z
xyz_1567.n28     2019-10-09T10:34:38.000000Z
```

Whenever there is a duplicate in the 'id' column, we need to compare the 'date' column of the duplicate rows and remove the row with the earlier date. In the example above, the first and third rows share the same 'id' value. The date of row three is later than the one of row one, so row three would be kept. Output:

```
id               date
abc_2791.b87     2015-04-07T12:04:06.000000Z
xyz_1567.n28     2019-10-09T10:34:38.000000Z
```

Finding duplicates could be achieved fairly easily with awk or sort, comparing dates isnt hard either. The hard part is combining the two - at least for me.

Comment: `Finding duplicates could be achieved fairly easily with awk or sort, comparing dates isnt hard either` So could you provide template code for both? Combining is quite easy `awk '{if (length(arr[$1])) { if (greater_date(arr[$1], $2)) arr[$1]=$2; } else arr[$1]=$2 } END { for i in arr ....})`. Basically save current value. Check if previous value exists, and if new value is encountered, update if better date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort -rk2 file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

Sort the file by date (the second column) and then remove the duplicates. This way you keep the most recent uniques per first column.

---

Or with one awk script

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} $2>a[$1] {a[$1]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result. Please check, this is without awk.

```
head -1 1.txt > new_uniqfile.txt;  # to get the header
#logic to get max value for a given id
for item in `tail -n+2 1.txt|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq`;
do 
grep $item 1.txt|sort -rk1,2|head -1 >> new_uniqfile.txt;
done

#prints the content from new file with unique values
cat new_uniqfile.txt
```